# Git isolate last two commits on two branch

Tags: git

My master last three commits:

```
... -> C -> B -> A
```

I'd like to isolate B and A commits in two different branches, so I want commits history of master, and the two new branches, like this:

master:

```
... -> C
```

branch-B:

```
... -> C -> B
```

branch-A:

```
... -> C -> A
```

I found way to do it for master and commit B branch, but I don't know how to do for commit A branch:

```
git checkout master
git branch commit-A
git reset --hard HEAD^
git branch commit-B // commit-B HEAD to commit B
git reset --hard HEAD^^ // master HEAD to commit C
git checkout commit-A
??? // how to do like if commit B did not happen ? I don't like git revert because it adds a new commit.
git push --all
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use cherry-pick

> git checkout master  //A
>
> git checkout (SHA1 of C) //You are in 'detached HEAD' state.
>
> git checkout -b branch_b // create and checkout branch_b from C (parent)
>
> git cherry-pick (SHA1 of B)
>
> git checkout (SHA1 of C) //You are in 'detached HEAD' state.
>
> git checkout -b branch_a // create and checkout branch_a from C (parent)
>
> git cherry-pick (SHA1 of A)
>
> git checkout master // A
>
> git reset --hard HEAD~2 // move HEAD 2 commits back

That's it :)